# Can referencing System.Web in WinForm .NET application have bad effects?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.web

I need to reference the [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) Class, and I mainly use 4 methods from the `HttpUtility Class`.

Namely:

1. `UrlDecode(String)`
2. `UrlEncode(String)`
3. `HtmlEncode(String)`
4. `HtmlDecode(String)`

My applications are multi-threaded, so is it referencing to `System.Web` 100% for a `Winform` application?

Comment: Follow this link for some step by step on how to correct your issue http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7301dec4-4b96-444d-88bb-630125d080e4/

Comment: well i have linked it properly, i just want to make sure using it in winform is safe

Comment: you can reference web methods in your win forms perhaps you should proceed with what you are trying to do.. then if you have issues or questions after that.. then report back here for some suggestions why not `Consume a Web Service` can you explain more about what you are wanting to do

Comment: i havent got any issues. i asked this question just for sake of confirmation

Comment: There's never any such limitations, as far as I know. Not for WinForms, anyway. I know some things don't work from Windows services, but in WinForms, anything should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4.5 you can use System.Net.WebUtility, it has all methods that you need, here is the info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx

And you can safely reference system.web from WinForms application anyway. Downside is that you can't use Client profile, it's a smaller download for your clients. For example NET 3.5 Client profile is 28 MB vs 150 MB for full profile

Comment: thnx for the info, but i am not ready to upgrade to .NET 4.5 or even 4.0 yet, many of my client are still using .net 2.0 or 3.5 only on windows xp

Answer (score 0):

From the Solution Explorer, right click to the project, select Add->Reference... and select System.Web.